# Change order of classes in column

Tags: r, datetime, join, posixct, column-types

I have an date-time object like:

`one <- structure(1678982734, class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = "UTC")`,
but when I try to join it with another dataframe where the classes are switched around, e.g,
`two <- structure(1678982734, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")` the join is failing. How can I tell R to switch the order of the class vector that defines the column type?

For anyone running into the same issue I'm pasting my actual error message from my overlapping join in `dplyr`:

```
Error in `full_join()`:
! Can't join `x$timestamp` with `y$deploy_on_date` due to incompatible types.
ℹ `x$timestamp` is a <datetime<UTC>>.
ℹ `y$deploy_on_date` is a <POSIXt>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: How is the object with `class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct")` created?

Comment: You could do `class(one) <- rev(class(one))`. But it sounds like a bug in whatever function is returning the "POSIXt" first. The classes should go from most specific to least specific.

Comment: Ah, ok MrFlick, maybe this is a bug to file with the package that brings in my data from ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with whatever created the object with `class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct")`. As [@MrFlick commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247242/change-order-of-classes-in-column#comment136182214_77247242) the 'class' vector should be in order of inheritance. 'POSIXct' inherits from 'POSIXt', not the other way around.

In addition, 'POSIXt' is a "virtual" class, which means you can't create an object that is just `class = "POSIXt"`. The only reason it exists is so 'POSIXct' and 'POSIXlt' objects can be operated on together (e.g. subtracting a 'POSIXct' object from a 'POSIXlt' object).

Also as MrFlick said, you can reverse the class vector if it's malformed.

```r
check_posix_class <- function(x) {
    if (identical(class(x), c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"))) {
        class(x) <- rev(class(x))
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Comment: I've filed a bug https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/issues/86

Comment: @Nova awesome! Thanks for being a great community member.